# Stop users from deleting attachments in outlook through C# code

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to stop users from deleting attachments in outlook mail Item either with right clicking and select remove or delete by pressing delete key using c# code

Comment: Your sentence structure is wonky. Are you trying to write a function in C# that prevents users from deleting attachments, or are you specifically trying to prevent a C# program from deleting attachments?

Comment: Hi Jim, I am creating a vsto addin, in that addin I specifically trying to write a function in c# that prevent users from deleting attachments from outlook mail item having a specific subject. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no BeforeAttachmentDelete event that can be intercepted. So the only way to do this is to "repurpose" the context menu to intercept the button click and cancel it.  See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944181(v=office.12).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/63aef709-e1d3-b1a6-76af-b568ad0e69ae(Office.15).aspx